# Get access to div from code behind task

Tags: c#, asp.net, task, code-behind

I need to create an application which should be able to manipulating a div content from code behind. But I need to update this one div without reloading the page. The function I use is based on tasks. I just start with this technology. Here is my code:

```
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public static System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl elem = null;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            elem  = div1;
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TaskClass c = new TaskClass ();
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => c.Execute());
        }
    }

    class TaskClass 
    {
        public async Task Execute()
        {
            _Default.elem.InnerHtml = "123";
        }
    }

    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Async="true" CodeBehind="Page.aspx.cs" Inherits="Class1._Default" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form runat="server">
            <div id="div1" style="border:1px solid; width:800px; height:200px;overflow:auto;" runat="server"></div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The problem is that div content is not changing. If I try add some content without using tasks it works. Is there way to use aspx and tasks in one project?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid what you want to do is much more complex than what you might expect. The web operates via requests and responses. Normally there is no constant connection between the page and the server. Once you send the response you cannot change it and this is why your code is not changing anything. There are two ways to do what you want.

1. Polling - you write JavaScript or use server side controls (for example UpdatePanel with timer) which periodically gets the latest state of the task from the server and updates the UI. With this approach you should be careful because making the request too often will be a performance problem or even data usage problem on mobile devices. On the other hand if you make the request not often enough your notification will not display on time and there will be a potentially long period before your complete task is displayed in the UI.
2. Use a persistent connection. These days there are ways to have a persistent connection to the page. Sadly they work quite differently from the way normal web pages work. Therefore you cannot do it within your page code. You should check some tutorials about frameworks like SignalR. It is not very hard to implement but it is completely different service and way of communicating with the page. Basically you won't be changing the page as much as writing a separate service.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I think that the quickest way to do this is implement websocket (external libraries). I would like to solve this problem in another way but it seems the websockets are incredibly universal :)

Comment: Use SignalR instead of raw Web Sockets (it works over web sockets when supported and the API is easier). Also if you can tolerate periods of like 15-20 seconds where the data is not updated you can easily do it with polling (even with update panel + timer polling without writing JavaScript)